# PhP PDO make query to ignore transaction inside a beginTransaction-commit bloc

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a query in a loop :

```
<?php
    try 
    {
        // I ommit the instanciation step of those variables
        $dsn, $user, $pass, $p1, $2, $pdo, $query1, $query2;

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        $p1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
        $p2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);

        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        for($i = 0; $i < 99; $i++)
        {
            if( ! $p1->execute() ) 
            {
                $pdo->rollBack();
                break;
            }

            // I want to prevent THIS query to be part of the transaction
            $p2->execute();
        }

        $pdo->commit();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

**Question**

I would like the `$p2->execute();` not to be part of the transaction. How would I do this ? Is there any command to make this query ignore its inner transaction bloc ?

**Possible alternative**

I have made it work using two instance of PDO like following :

```
<?php
    try 
    {
        // I ommit the instanciation step of those variables
        $dsn, $user, $pass, $p1, $p2, $pdo, $pdo2 $query1, $query2;

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        $pdo2 = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        $p1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
        $p2 = $pdo2->prepare($query2);

        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        for($i = 0; $i < 99; $i++)
        {
            if( ! $p1->execute() ) 
            {
                $pdo->rollBack();
                break;
            }

            // This actually skips the transaction of the first connection
            $p2->execute();
        }

        $pdo->commit();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: transactions are per-connection. if you want to execute a query "outside" of that transaction, you'll have to establish a second connection to the server.

Comment: Make one connection and use it to exhaustion. Making multiple connections is where you get into trouble in a hurry due to sequencing problems.

Comment: @tadman I can tell one case this connection redundancy is usefull : in my case this programm reflect my php app that queue some **long** process. The first query, `$p1->execute()` is processing (reading a file and adress the value). The second query, `$p2->execute()` is updating the current progress of the process. I need this last query to be updated *in real time*, meaning it has to insert the progress as the program goes by. If you have an alternative I am open to suggests.

Comment: Due to [MVCC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html) you can't do this. A transaction creates a sort of parallel universe that only gets merged back into the main one if and *only* if you commit it, and as long as that remains uncommitted none of your changes are visible to other connections. As Marc says, transactions are per connection and there's no way around this. It's just how the database works. If you need the other connection to operate independently you'll have to take that into account.